# meaning of "hunt for tax exemption"

Tags: word-usage

> Today I can hunt for tax exemptions. I'm gonna be an actuary.

In the above sentence, what is the meaning of "hunt for tax exemption"?

Is it meaning that he (I in the example) can hunt someone who did not pay tax illegally?

Comment: "Hunt for" means look for, and a "tax exemption" is a way to legally save money on tax.  So the first sentence means that today, he looks for (and presumably finds) ways to legally reduce his taxes.  But the second sentence is totally confusing - it's unclear what tax exemption hunting has to do with being an actuary, except that they are both, I guess, somewhat mathematical activities.

Comment: @cruthers Those are the sentences that appear in the Zutopia animation. :-)

Comment: Ah - this is apparently a known issue.  https://www.reddit.com/r/zootopia/comments/49q1bu/spoilers_everything_wrong_with_zootopia/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hunt for" here means search for.

To be exempt from something means to not be required to do something that normally is required. Tax exemptions are situations where you're not required to pay taxes; finding them would presumably mean you spend less money on taxes. No, there's no implication of illegal activity.

An actuary is a professional that deals with statistics such as the likelihood of an insurance payout. This doesn't actually have anything to do with taxes, but we can assume the person speaking doesn't know that and treat it like he said "I'm gonna be an accountant." That's like someone who never gets to go outside suddenly getting a reason to walk a mile in the woods and excitedly saying "I'm gonna be an explorer" - it's not actually that impressive, and it's nothing compared to the people who do it full time, but we can pretend that we're doing something awesome anyway.